# How to make entire screen blackish when jquery ui popup is visible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How to make entire screen blackish when jquery ui popup is visible?

Comment: something like lightbox? it show only phpup and every else blackish?

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want a [modal](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-modal) dialog?

Then you can just set `modal` to `true` if you're using the jQuery dialog.

```
$(".selector").dialog({ modal: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS file that came with your jQuery UI download, look for the .ui-widget-overlay selector. Try something like:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
background-color: #333;
opacity:0.5;
filter:Alpha(Opacity=50);
}
```